# Meaning of "desk warrior"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I'm not sure about the meaning of *desk warrior*, as it appears in this passage taken from [The Economist](http://www.economist.com/node/21541713) (my boldface emphasis):

> Those [South Korean students, my note] who score well can enter one of
>   Korea’s best universities, which has traditionally guaranteed them a
>   job-for-life as a high-flying bureaucrat or **desk warrior** at a
>   *chaebol* (conglomerate).

I cannot find it in the dictionaries at my disposal. It seems to me that it is a sort of ironic or even disapproving epithet for a particular kind of white collar employees who hold a position of some responsibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Desk warrior* is a similar phrase to *[desk jockey](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/desk%20jockey)*, a mildly dismissive term for someone working in a faceless office job. It is an ironic usage, as *warrior* and *jockey* evoke more active or glamorous occupations, although *desk jockey* was probably originally a play on *disc jockey*. Other slang terms for office workers include *corporate drones*, *cubicle rats*, or *office monkeys*.

There are many connotations to draw; depending on the context, an office worker may be

- a mere "cog in the machine," a forgettable or ignorable part of a giant heartless machine
- someone who working in administration as opposed to "real" work in the field, e.g. a hospital director as opposed to a surgeon, a university provost as opposed to a professor, or a soldier or police officer assigned to work in the office
- a bureaucrat, someone who insists on routines and procedures at the expense of the "big picture"

or something else.

Comment: That's what I thought at first, but if you read the entire article I think you'll see that they're saying "desk warrior" as a GOOD thing.   The article is about how so much rides on the Korean university exams.

Comment: @Lynn Being a desk warrior **at a chaebol** is certainly a good thing, at least in South Korea. My Korean grandparents would be prouder of the grandchild in middle management for a subsidiary of an LG or Kumho than the one who is an entrepreneur. The desirability is related to social status, not the quality of life of a salaryman.

Comment: Agreed.  So... in the OP's context, the idea that someone can be virtually guaranteed a job as a "desk warrior at a chaebol" seems in contradiction to your answer equating the term with desk jockey / cog in the machine.  Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @Lynn What *The Economist* considers a good thing and what South Korean society considers a good thing are not necessarily congruent.

Answer (score 2):

I've never heard that particular phrase before, but based on the context it appears to be a clever twist on [road warrior](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/road%20warrior).

A road warrior is a corporate employee who spends a lot of time on the road traveling.   Desk warrior would be, by extension, a corporate employee who spends a lot of time at their desk.

Generally road warriors are not a very envied position, but urban dictionary [reports](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=road%20warrior) that the term road warrior is sometimes used "...to glamorize, romanticize and/or rationalize their lonely profession..."  It seems like the author is using the term in this context.

In a nutshell - if the students do well on their exams they get a prestigious position as a "high-flying bureaucrat or desk warrior", but if they fail their exams they are relegated to a lesser position.

Answer (score 2):

The use of *desk* as an adjective, modifying a more "glamorous" noun, is sometimes used to describe those who spend most of their working day behind a desk.  Such terminology is often used to deride or sympathize with the one who is tied to the desk, instead of where the action is.

In addition to *desk warrior*, I've also seen *desk pilot* (particularly common in flying squadons), and *[desk jockey](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22desk%20jockey%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1965,cd_max:1995&lr=lang_en)* (which [this Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=desk%20warrior,%20desk%20jockey,%20desk%20pilot&year_start=1890&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) says is most common of the three).

> But when are you going to get it through your bureaucratic heads that I am a scientist? A *field* man, not a damned desk pilot! ([Ian Douglas](http://books.google.com/books?id=fImroJx9R6oC&pg=PA81&dq=%22desk%20pilot%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ISPOT_6GEab26AHahtmVDA&ved=0CFsQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22desk%20pilot%22&f=false))